# Storefront event webhooks in Shopware 6 app development

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I developing an app and basicly if an user loaded a product in the storefront it should send a request to my server. So i thought thats possible with webhooks. But unfortunately there is no webhook for this case.

The closest thing i could find is the `product.written` webhook but that seems useless for my case.
Anyone has an idea how i could realize my request?

I use Shopware 6.4.11.1 as development enviroment.

Comment: I guess such a web-hook be fired very often? What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @Alex Taht's right. and it should be fired very often. I need this for server-side tracking.
So the idea is someone visit a page (i.e. product lissting, product detail). When that happen a server-side call should made to a server with all relevant data. And all that whitin shopwares app system.

Comment: I just mentioned that because I think it would be very inperformant. I don't know if such a hook exists

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found any appropriate webhook in the [webhook events reference](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/webhook-events-reference), this may be doable in a slightly different way, without using the Shopware App Webhook mechanic.

In the [Shopware documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/webhook-events-reference) there are shown ways to add Storefront scripts to an app. There is even an example for `product-page-loaded`. You would be able to execute some of your own code in there, but honestly I have not tried to ping external servers like this and I can't tell you that this will surely work.

You could also potentially add some [custom JS code](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/storefront#custom-assets-in-apps) that pings your server with the appropriate info.

Unfortunately I don't think you can compel Shopware to send a request from its backend on a `ProductPageLoadedEvent`